# How to get all values from an object array and insert all values into a array

Tags: angular, typescript

I have question about how to get all values from an object array and insert all values into an array.

the object array looks like this:

```
obj = [
  {
     id: "1111",
     name: "aaa"
  },
  {
     id: "2222",
     name: "bbb"
  },
  {
     id: "3333",
     name: "ccc"
  }
]
```

I just want to get a Id array such as

```
ids = ["1111", "2222", "3333"]
```

in Angular Typescript how should the code look like?

Comment: What have you tried till now? Please show your attempt. Your initial approach will help us build on top of it to get an answer.

Comment: [Array#map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

Answer (score 2):

You want the map operator :  `obj.map(o => o.id)`